# How to write function that take a list and number X .If X exist in list in index ‘m’, it should return sum of elements of list from index ‘m’

Tags: python, list, function, printing, range

```
def func(x):
    lst=list(map(int,input("Enter a list of numbers: ").split()))
    flag=0
    num=0
    for i in lst:
         if x==i:
                flag=1
                
    if flag==1:
        ab=lst.index(x)
        for i in range(ab,len(lst),1):
            num=lst.index(ab)
            num=num+lst[i]
            print(num)
    return num
        
    
y=input("Enter a number present in the list: ")
print(func(y))
```

Above is the function to find all numbers and sum from index m. It takes a number from the user,gets the index and prints the sum of the number from index m. But the code output is 0 in this case

Comment: Try removing line `num=lst.index(ab)` in for loop.

Comment: still 0 as the output@DarrylG

Comment: I would use `sum` and `itertools.dropwhile` and not bother with explicit iteration or indices.

Comment: Also, need to convert y to int, i.e. y = int(input("Enter a number present in the list: "))

Comment: Also, it seems backwards to prompt for "a number present in the list" before the list even exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can use `split()` with empty parameter.

And a solution of your problem is:

```
    def func(x):
    a=input("Enter list of Numbers: ")
    lst=list()
    for i in a:
        try:
            i=int(i)
            lst.append(i)
        except:
            pass
    num=0
    x=int(x)
    for i in (lst):
        if x==i:
            index=lst.index(x)
            for i in range(index,len(lst),1):
                num=num+lst[i]
    return num
        
        
    
y=input("Enter a number present in the list: ")
print(func(y))
```

instead of `map` i have used the `for loop` to covert the string to a integer list.
then if `x==i` i searched the index of x in the list and from the index i start to sum the numbers again using a `for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def func(y, lst):
    try:
        return sum(lst[lst.index(y):])
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{y} is not in {lst}")

lst = list(map(int,input("Enter a list of numbers: ").split()))
y = int(input("Enter a number present in the list: "))
total = func(y, lst)
print(total)
```

Output:

```
Enter a list of numbers: 10 20 30 40 50 60
Enter a number present in the list: 30
180
```